# How to check whether a clone of an element exists in the document -- Jquery/JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, drag-and-drop, clone

I have some draggable elements in the DOM, which if dropped become draggable disabled. Now there can be only one element in the droppable at a time. So if the user drags another draggable and drops it, the previous dropped element must get removed from the droppable and the currently dragged element must replace it in the droppable.
How can I do this??

This is my draggable:

```
$('#draggable').draggable({
  helper: "clone",
  revert: 'invalid',
  containment: '#drag-drop-wrapper',
  appendTo: '#doc-container'
});
```

And my droppable

```
$('#droppable').droppable({
  accept: ".session",
  drop: function(event,ui){
    //Need the code to replace old dropped item with new dropped item
  }
});
```

Please help.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does the `appendTo` option for `draggable` really do what you intend? From the docs: *"The element passed to or selected by the `appendTo` option will be used as the draggable helper's container during dragging. By default, the helper is appended to the same container as the draggable."* http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/#option-appendTo That doesn't quite seem like what you want.

Comment: I deleted my answer, I guess I'm not seeing what you're trying to do. Good luck.

Comment: Sorry will edit that part in a moment :)

Comment: Is the point to remove the dragged element, or snap it back to where it came from?  $().remove()  in your droppable would remove the element.

Comment: Basically I need to remove it. Because as you can see I am only dragging the clone and not the original draggable.